# How can I identify two closes below a Moving Average and color them in the chart

Tags: pine-script

I am still new to coding and pine and I hope someone can help me out.

I want to identify in the chart if we have two closes below a Moving Average and highlight them. Identifying one was pretty simple but getting two in a row drives me crazy.

Here is my code for one close below

```
bgcolor(color=crossunder(close, ma) ? color.new(color.green,90) : na, title="2nd Close below MA")
```

I tried the following but it did not work:

```
twoLowerClosesMA = crossunder(close[1],ma) and crossunder(close,ma)
bgcolor(twoLowerClosesMA ? color.new(color.red,90) : na)
```

But with the second one I did not get any result.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
maCrossunder = crossunder(close, ma)
twoLowerClosesMA = maCrossunder[1] and close < ma
```